# In Eclipse, why can I run simple program without Maven but not with?

Tags: eclipse, maven

I created a Maven project in Eclipse. Experimentally tried running a HelloWorld program and it failed with "Cannot find or load main class..." error. When I disable Maven, the program runs. Could this be a problem in the pom file? Or some other problem? Importantly, the target folder is empty.

Comment: Could you show the pom?

Answer (score 0):

you need to enable "auto build" on the project from the project menu. then then clean the project first time. I hope this will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is what it looks like. If a Maven project in Eclipse can't build completely, then the class files are not created hence the error I am seeing. If it is a non-Maven project, apparently individual files get compiled even if some other files within the project have compilation errors. So it is necessary to make sure every class compiles in an Eclipse Maven project if you want to run code that itself has no compilation errors.